# Cloudwatch Insight visualization

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a log with api Names and requestIds and what I am trying to do is to visualize in cloud watch insight. If I run the following query it works to see the table, but not working to visualize. I know I need to use `bin`, but keep using wrong, so the graph does not work

How can I visualize the following query

```
stats count(*) as requestId by apiName
    | sort requestId desc
    | limit 10
```

Comment: Actually nothing wrong with this query. Even if I add ``bin`` I still get the same result. The issue is that Cloudwatch metrics expects metrics with predefined dimensions, whereas this query involves aggregation over dynamic fields.